# Why do I got TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; invalid argument?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I'm testing this funciton with JUnit and I getting **TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException;**

```
public boolean delete(long idTaskPriority) {
    String sql = "DELETE FROM a_taskPriority WHERE idTaskPriority=:idTaskPriority";

    MapSqlParameterSource params = 
        new MapSqlParameterSource("idTaskPriority", idTaskPriority);

    return jdbc.update(sql, params) == 1;
}
```

**Error trace:**

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
SQL [DELETE FROM a_taskPriority WHERE idTaskPriority=:idTaskPriority]; 
Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
```

---

I've tried as well with another params type but I got more or less the same error

```
public boolean delete(long idTaskPriority) {

    String sql = "DELETE FROM a_taskPriority WHERE idTaskPriority=:idTaskPriority";

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("idTaskPriority", idTaskPriority);

    return jdbc.update(sql, params) == 1;
}
```

In this case I got the **error trace**

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
SQL [DELETE FROM a_taskPriority WHERE idTaskPriority=:idTaskPriority]; 
Invalid argument value: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

I'm passing a long = 1, to try the funciton but it doesn't work.

---

Priority class

```
package com.javalabs.web.dao;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("priority")
public class Priority {

    private long idTaskPriority = 0;
    private long sortOrder = 0;
    private String aka = "";
    private String priority = "";
    private Date timestamp;

    public Priority() {
    }

    public Priority(long idTaskPriority) {
        this.idTaskPriority = idTaskPriority;
    }

    /**
     * @param priority
     */
    public Priority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    /**
     * @param order
     * @param aka
     * @param priority
     */
    public Priority(long sortOrder, String aka, String priority) {
        super();
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
        this.aka = aka;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public void setIdTaskPriority(long idTaskPriority) {
        this.idTaskPriority = idTaskPriority;
    }

    public long getIdTaskPriority() {
        return idTaskPriority;
    }

    public long getSortOrder() {
        return sortOrder;
    }

    public void setSortOrder(long sortOrder) {
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public String getAka() {
        return aka;
    }

    public void setAka(String aka) {
        this.aka = aka;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Priority [idTaskPriority=" + idTaskPriority + ", sortOrder=" + sortOrder + ", aka=" + aka
                + ", priority=" + priority + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + "]";
    }

}
```

PriorityDao class

```
public class PriorityDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(jdbc);
    }

...
    public boolean delete(long idTaskPriority) {
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource(
                "idTaskPriority", idTaskPriority);

        String sql = "DELETE FROM a_taskPriority WHERE idTaskPriority=:idTaskPriority";

        return jdbc.update(sql, params) == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try Long instead of long ?

Comment: yes, I tried and it doesn't work :(

Comment: I even tried a simple query insert into that works in mysql and it doesn't work with jdbc.update without parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` for `update` operation.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene Evdokimov I hadn't gotten your answer! You were right.

Answer (score 0):

The last attempt I've tried, it was by doing without parameters and replace the id directly in the sql.

```
public boolean delete(long idTaskPriority) {

    String sql = "DELETE FROM a_taskPriority WHERE idTaskPriority=" + idTaskPriority;

    return jdbc.update(sql) == 1;
}
```

And this way it is not as simple as it should be with parameters and it works.
I can not figure out what is wrong with parameters, MapSqlParameterSource or HashMap.